# How to set Google SSO CallbackPath to HTTPS in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, google-oauth

Currently have a project using the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` package for Google SSO for accessing a website.  The website is behind a load balancer that handles HTTPS.  In GCP, the authorized redirect URI is `http://example.com/signin-google`.  Received a message from Google today saying that HTTP redirect URIs are deprecated and need to be updated to HTTPS.

Using the below code in Startup.Auth.cs to configure it:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});            
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "myid",
    ClientSecret = "mysecret"              
});
```

How do I set the callback path to be https?  I noticed there is a CallbackPath option but that just seems to be for changing the default /signin-google to something else.

Comment: OAuth has configuration in 3 locations.  in Azure AD (B2C?) app registration, in your application and with the identity provider, in this case Google.  You can make that change to meet your needs for a custom URL, but you need to address the change in all three places.